# Pycharm Linux "cannot open Local Terminal"

Tags: python, pycharm, raspbian

I've been digging through the internet forever trying to find how to fix this issue on opening the terminal in Pycharm. Everything is either for Windows "cmd.exe" or the solution just does not work. I'm just trying to use the Terminal for Django. Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm using a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Linux. Here's what it says when I try to open the terminal:

```
Cannot open Local Terminal
Failed to start [/bin/bash, --rcfile, /home/pi/Desktop/pycharm-community-2019.3.1/plugins/terminal/jediterm-bash.in, -i] in /home/pi/PycharmProjects/web

See your idea.log (Help | Show Log in File Manager) for the details.
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs yet?

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove Yes, it says "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '/home/pi/Desktop/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2019.3.1/lib/pty4j-native/linux/x86/libpty.so':
/home/pi/Desktop/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2019.3.1/lib/pty4j-native/linux/x86/libpty.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 6):

OK . I had the same problem, and this is the solution:

ONce Pycharm Installed .. follow this steps

open terminal in your raspberry
and type:

git clone https://github.com/JetBrains/pty4j.git

cd pty4j/native

gcc -fPIC -c *.c

gcc -shared -o libpty.so *.o

** now .. be carefull , and check your installation Pycharm´s folder name and write it accordingly.

and type:

cp libpty.so /opt/*** pycharm *** /lib/pty4j-native/linux/x86/

done !

Comment: Perfect ! It worked using latest PyCharm pro on latest pi 4 on September 2020...YOU ARE THE MAN !

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in ubuntu PyCharm community edition. The issue resolved by clearing invalidate caches.

- File -> Invalidate Cache
- Select 'Clear file system cache and Local History'
- Select 'VCS Log caches and indexes
- Select 'Invalidate and Restart'

Comment: Weird, but yes, that also solved the issue on my setup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to see idea log [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)

. top menu -> help -> Compress Logs and Show in Explorer